# How to resolve errors CS1003: Syntax error, '(' expected, and error CS1031: Type expected?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a 2d platform game in the Unity Engine Version Num - 2018.4.9f1 with c# compiled with Visual Studio Version Num - 1.38.1.

The console in Unity Engine is showing two errors listed below with the code I have in the Visual Studio.

> error CS1003: Syntax error, '(' expected
>
> error CS1031: Type expected

My code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[RequireComponent(typeof)(Text))]
public class CountdownText : MonoBehaviour {

    public delegate void CountdownFinished();
    public static event CountdownFinished OnCountdownFinished;

    Text countdown;

    void OnEnable() {
        countdown = GetComponent<Text>();
        countdown.text = "3";
        StartCoroutine("Countdown");
    }

    IEnumerator Countdown() {
        int count = 3;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            countdown.text = (count - i).ToString();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        }

        OnCountdownFinished();
    }
}
```

Comment: `(typeof)(Text))` How many `(` are there? How many `)`?

Comment: [`[RequireComponent(typeof(Text))]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RequireComponent(typeof)(Text))` is wrong. It should be `RequireComponent(typeof(Text))`

The typeof operator obtains the System.Type instance for a type.